# Polyculture achievement: Is there any way to know which ones I shipped 15 of?

Tags: achievements, stardew-valley

For the Polyculture achievement, is there an easy way to know which crops I've sent 15 of and what do I still have to ship? Or do I have to keep track with good ol' pen and paper?

I'm not above using mods, so I would put mods as a possible answer, if you got any that would do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information is easily found by hovering over individual items in the menu's Collections tab, as shown in this picture:

[image: The Collections tab listing how many tomatoes have been shipped]

Comment: Oh I play with controller so I never hovered over them! Useful!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/StardewValley/comments/ctmm0w/what_am_i_missing_for_the_ship_15_of_every_crop/) on Reddit:

> Go to your collections page and hover your mouse over each crop. There should be a part that says “number shipped”.